# Create dataframe in a "for" loop, in which a function can be applied to them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, global

The first for loop seems to work. However, when I move onto doing a groupby function on the next dataframe, something about the global variable in the for loop doesn't store the dataframe's correctly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
chan_group = list(df_2017['Default Channel Grouping'].value_counts().index)
    

gbl = globals()

for i in chan_group:
    gbl['df_'+i] = df_2017[df_2017['Default Channel Grouping']==i]
    
g_chang_group = df_(Other), df_Aggregators, df_Direct, df_Display, df_Email, df_Email alerts, df_Newsletter, df_Organic Search, df_Paid Search, df_Partner referral, df_Referral, df_Retargeting, df_Social

for i in g_chan_group:
    x = i.groupby(['Month']).sum()
```

Comment: Have you tried `df_2017.groupby(["Default Channel Grouping", "Month"]).sum()` ?

Comment: No worries! Usually pandas works best without iteration so it's best to look at the built-ins first =)

Answer (score 0):

From @Nathan Furnal

`df_2017.groupby(["Default Channel Grouping", "Month"]).sum()`